# Blockchain 2 days still no confirmation

Tags: blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions

I am so much worried. I don't know what to do.

https://blockchain.info/tx/41112430b191b5be2b4cd26e6f4203f3156f4437c72bd2ef242f0e9f15f75c82

Comment: Please guys help! It's really urgent

Answer (score 0):

Can you see blockchain? 
https://blockchain.info/en/unconfirmed-transactions 
If unconfirmed transaction will be less as now (~70 000) then you will see your btc ;)